# Switching classes in kivy without screenmanger

Tags: python, oop, kivy, kivy-language

I am creating a game and I want to have different levels and different setting feauters, like play button and so on. So for that I need many screens especially for my levels. My classes inherit from Widgets, so I cant use a screenmanager.  But I would love to use it. My idea is to clear all widegts and then render new widgets. But I don't really know how to start and implement my idea. Could anybody help. Here is my code.

```
class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    ship = ObjectProperty(None)
    enemy = ObjectProperty(None)
    def serve_ball(self,*args):
        self.ball.x = self.ship.x
        self.ball.y = self.ship.y
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(5,0).rotate(90)
        if self.ball.y > self.height:
            self.ball.x = self.ship.x
            self.ball.y = self.ship.y
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load('laser.wav')
        self.sound.play()


    def random_generator(self,x,y):
        return random.randint(x,y)

    enemies = ListProperty([])

    def add_enemy(self, *args):
        enemy = Enemy()
        enemy.pos = (random.randint(0,600), randint(200,600))
        self.add_widget(enemy)
        self.enemies.append(enemy)
    And so on lots of code I don't think that everything else is important
```

My enemy and ship class

```
class Enemy(Widget):
    x_change = NumericProperty(3)
    y_change = NumericProperty(-50)
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def collision(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            self.y = 1000
            self.score += 5
           # enemy1.y = randint(300, 500)
            ball.x = -1000
            ball.y = self.height / self.width

    def move(self, *args):
        self.x -= self.x_change
        if self.x >= self.parent.width - 64:
            self.x_change = 3
            self.y += self.y_change
        elif self.x <= 0:
            self.x_change = -3
            self.y += self.y_change
        if self.y < 0:
            print('Game Over')
            self.clear_widgets()





class SpaceShip(Widget):
    pass
```

My main app class

```
class PongApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        # game.serve_ball()
        # pro second 60 frames are shown
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update,1/60)
        return game
```

Some of my kv code

```
<Enemy>:
    size_hint: None,None
    size: 64,64
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size: self.size
            source:'alien.png'



<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    ship: space_ship
    start_button: start_button
    resume_button:resume_button

    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'background.png'
    Label:
        font_size: 40
        x:root.width/ 1/4 +70
        y:root.height -350
        text: 'Your score :'

    Label:
        font_size: 40
        x:root.width/ 1/2
        y:root.height -350
        #text: str(root.Enemy.score)
```